# How to keep python code in cloud and then make multiple users execute the code on their local machines?

Tags: python, windows, shell, cloud

I have a python CLI interface tool which is used by more than 80 people in my team.
Every time we make changes to our code and release it, users also have to download the latest code on their
**Windows Machine** and then run it.

Like this we have other tools as well like GCC, Company's internal software to be installed on every users PC.

Users sometimes face issues in installing the software and upgrading to newer version of Python CLI tool.

I want these tools and softwares to be managed at a single place and then user can access them from there.

How to resolve this problem on Windows Platform?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the environment, some ideas;

- could share a onedrive folder and sync it from there.
- Group policy that runs an install script on startup

Answer (score 1):

The easiest no-setup solution would be for the tool to autoupdate itself. Make the main script be the "loader", which checks if there is a newer version of the tool, and downloads it if there is, replacing the sources in the project; only then `import` the actual tool and run it. If you have `git` on each machine, updating is as easy as:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(["git", "pull"], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

from main import main
main()
```

EDIT: Answered the question in the title (about Python code).